# Scene Builder 2.0. FXML import not working

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0. version and I would like to import a FXML file under TabPane controller. My idea is that I will have one kind of container FXML file with TabPane and separate FXML files for things that will come inside of tabs. When I try to import FXML file where I have things that I would like to add under one tab, Scene Builder gives error message "Failed to import TabContents.fxml under TabPane". Why it is not possible to import anything under the TabPane? If I import same file directly under root StackPane everything works.

Comment: Having the same problem here. Can't find any answers online because nobody uses JavaFX

Answer (score 2):

## Three simple steps

1. Add a `StackPane` to the content area of your `Tab`, ensuring that it occupies 100% of the area.
2. Go to the Hierarchy view and select that `StackPane` you just added.
3. Include your `TabContents.fxml`. It should automatically be added to the created `StackPane` and should display as desired.

Also, to answer your additional question, importing it directly into the `TabPane` will render it as a `Graphic` rather than a `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** While the below works, it is best to add some sort of layout pane (like an `AnchorPane`) to each tab in your `TabPane`, select the `AnchorPane` pane in the hierarchy view on the left and then import your other fxml document into that, as opposed to importing directly into a `TabPane` (Perhaps if the root node of the document is a `Tab` it would work?).

---

Looks like a bug, for now:

- Cut your entire document hierarchy
- Add an empty stack pane
- Include your other FXML file
- Paste your document hierarchy into the stack pane
- Drag your FXML file into the appropriate place in your hierarchy
- Cut your new hierarchy (with your file included)
- Delete the now defunct stack pane
- Paste your hierarchy back in

And voila, working as intended!

Answer (score 1):

just add a new TabPane where you want and then edit your FXML code of the TabPane just added as following:

```
<TabPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="5000.0" prefWidth="5000.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
      <tabs>
          <Tab closable="false" text="MyTab1">
               <content>
<fx:include source="MyTab1.fxml" />
               </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab closable="false" text="MyTab2">
               <content>
<fx:include source="MyTab2.fxml" />
               </content>
          </Tab>
      </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

adding as many tab you need just adding more 'Tab' tags. 
'MyTab1.fxml' and 'MyTab2.fxml' are just fxml files contained in the same folder of the fxml file of the TabPane.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me selecting first the root node in the scene. Then I import de FXML and it is imported hanging from this root node. As the last step, I move the imported FXML to the place I want in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the FXML import can also fail when you have another FXML template included in the one you want to import. Something like:

```
  <fx:include source="top-menu-bar.fxml" />
```

Looks like SceneBuilder doesn't know where is top-menu-bar.fxml. The solution can be to work on the template separately and then adding those includes manually to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" >
 <children>
  <fx:include fx:id="includeID" source="includeSource.fxml" />
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The include file must be include in the children of a pane.